# SQL Server Replication filtering

Tags: sql-server, replication

We are replicating data between a SQL Server 2008 (Source) and a SQL Server 2012 (Destination). We have been asked to limit the data being replicated to what we require.

So, we could add a filter, BUT, the filter is based on something in another table. and we can't use a JOIN. (Transactional Replication).

But, I notice that in the editor for the WHERE clause, it allows this:

```
SELECT * FROM party WHERE party_id NOT IN (SELECT child_party_id FROM placement)
```

That's what we need to filter. Is the editor just allowing me to put something that won't work in, because the data in the destination doesn't seem filtered at all.

Comment: The filter_clause is just a where statement, not a whole select. I don't know if this will work (otherwise I'd have just put it as an answer), but try putting "party_id NOT IN (SELECT child_party_id FROM placement)". I suspect it won't work in the long run as replication isn't keeping track of changes to the placement table and making corresponding changes to the party table. A workaround might be to create and replicate an indexed view.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT * FROM party p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM placement
                 WHERE child_party_id = p.party_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had been in the same issue...its because trasactional replication will not repush the data after delete\update on subquery table(table used in where clause).

In your example,
SELECT * FROM party WHERE party_id NOT IN (SELECT child_party_id FROM placement)
Update on placement table will not tell replication to push row from table party.